# Greatest 'n' per group by month

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a mysql table with date, name and rating of a person. I need to build a query to show the best person of each month. The query above gives me maximum rating of the month but wrong name/id of person.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date,'%m.%Y') as date2, MAX(rating), name FROM test GROUP BY date2
```

Here's sqlfiddle with sample table: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4dd54b/9

I read several greatest-n-per-group topics, but those queries didn't work, I suppose it's because of grouping by DATE_FORMAT. So here I ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the `substring_index()`/`group_concat()` trick:

```
  SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%m.%Y') as date2, MAX(rating),
         substring_index(group_concat(name order by rating desc), ',', 1) as name
  FROM test
  GROUP BY date2;
```

Answer (score 0):

A faster solution might look like this - although removal of the DATE_FORMAT function altogether will speed things up even further...

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM test x
  JOIN
     ( SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m') dt
            , MAX(rating) max_rating 
         FROM test 
        GROUP
           BY DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m')
     ) y
    ON y.dt = DATE_FORMAT(x.date,'%Y-%m')
   AND y.max_rating = x.rating;
```